# How can we change header Text of a cell in TabView of webix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webix

I create a tabview with 2 cell( It's mean 2 tabs).

```
$scope.config = {
id: "accordion",
type: "accordion",
cols:[
  {
    id:"tabviewId",
    view: "tabview",
    cells: [{
    header: "headerTexthere",
    body: "..."
    },{
    }   
    ]   
  }
]
}
```

Now I want to change headerText in first tab.

```
var tabViewItemList = $$("tabviewId").getTabbar();
                var view = $$("tabviewId").getChildViews();
                var tab1 = view[0];
                tab1.$view.innerText = "avb";
```

I tried but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Check http://webix.com/snippet/53085773

```
var tabs = $$("tabviewId").getTabbar();
tabs.config.options[0].value = "My new text";
tabs.refresh();
```

tabview contains a "tabbar" and "multiview" widgets inside. So you can access a tabbar and use its API to change label on one of buttons.